# Existence of a minimizer for $\int_0^1|P(t)|\,{\rm d}t$.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $m > 0$ be a fixed integer. Show that among all the polynomials $P \in \Bbb C[X]$ with degree $\leq m$ and with $P(0)=1$, there is one that makes minimum the value $\int_0^1|P(t)|\,{\rm d}t$.

**My attempt:** Let ${\cal P}^m$ be the set of all the polynomials in $\Bbb C[X]$ with $P(0)=1$. I am aware that $$\|P\| = \int_0^1 |P(t)|\,{\rm d}t$$ is continuous because it is a norm. Since ${\cal P}^m$ and $\Bbb R$ have finite dimension, and $T: {\cal P}^m \to \Bbb R$ given by $T(P) = P(0)$ is linear, $T$ is continuous, so: $$ \{ P \in {\cal P}^m \mid P(0) =  1 \} = T^{-1}(\{1\})$$ is a closed set. If I could show that it is bounded, we would have compactness (because of finite dimension) and I could conclude the result by Weierstrass' extremum theorem. But if you make $m=1$ and look at $T$ as a projection, it is clear that the set is not compact, so I don't think I am in the right way.

Is there a way to save my work so far? If someone can give me hints it's also ok. Thanks.

Comment: But $P/2$ won't satisfy $(P/2) (0) = 1$.

Comment: Why is it obvious that the set is not compact? The proof looks correct to me.

Comment: @IvoTerek : Right >_<

Comment: @Farnight If you look at $m=1$ and identify ${\cal P}^1 \equiv \Bbb R^2$ the set would be a infinite vertical line, no?

xavier02 Don't worry about it, we'll figure something out.

Comment: @Farnight : Yes. $\alpha X + 1$ will work for any $\alpha$. The sup norm of this goes to $\infty$ as $\alpha$ goes to $\infty$ and since we're in finite dim, all norms are equivalent.

Comment: @IvoTerek Oh, yea. Good point. I think I spotted the error. You can't say that $T^{-1}(\{1\})$ is compact. Only that it is closed. (You can say that it's compact if it was the image, not the inverse image, of a compact set by a continuous function)

Comment: Precisely! ${}{}$

Comment: You can restrict yourself to polynomials whose norm are $\le 1$ since you want to minimize the norm.

Comment: A clarification on @xavierm02 's comment: there is always one of norm $1$, namely the function which is identically $1$, so the preimage of $1$ among functions with norm at most $1$ is a closed, bounded, *nonempty* set, in a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Meaning that the unit ball is compact, ok. But I don't see how to use this here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key observation here is that the level sets of the function are compact (as you observed the set of all feasible points is not compact). In fact the set of all $P$ satisfying $P(0)=1$
$$
\int_0^1 |P(t)|dt\le 1
$$
is bounded in $L^1$. Now the underlying space is finite-dimensional, hence this set is compact (is it closed as the intersection of the $L^1$ unit ball with the closed subspace $\{P:P(0)=1\}$).

Now you can apply Weierstrass theorem.